# Error with authentication (Django Rest Framework + JWT Auth)

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I've been working on my first Django Rest Framework project and I'm having some trouble getting my JWT authentication to work properly. Upon logging into my (React) app, everything works as intended, but when coming back to the app after several hours and doing something in the site that requires authentication, I get the following error instead of the token being refreshed or redirected to my login screen.

[image]

I'm totally new to authentication, and my code for my JWT Auth is taken from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfYfvjP1hK8&list=PLOLrQ9Pn6caw0PjVwymNc64NkUNbZlhFw&index=4), so I'm not completely sure if I've goofed something up or if the tutorial code isn't working properly.

I suspect the issue is on the front-end, so here is my axios file where I handle the token refreshes (again, taken from the tutorial code)

```
const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('access_token'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json',
    },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    async function (error) {
        const originalRequest = error.config;

        if (typeof error.response === 'undefined') {
            alert(
                'A server/network error occurred. ' +
                'Looks like CORS might be the problem. ' +
                'Sorry about this - we will get it fixed shortly.'
            );
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            originalRequest.url === baseURL + 'token/refresh/'
        ) {
            window.location.href = '/login/';
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.data.code === 'token_not_valid' &&
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            error.response.statusText === 'Unauthorized'
        ) {
            const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

            if (refreshToken) {
                const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refreshToken.split('.')[1]));

                // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
                const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
                console.log(tokenParts.exp);

                if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
                    return axiosInstance
                        .post('/token/refresh/', {
                            refresh: refreshToken
                        })
                        .then((response) => {
                            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);
                            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh);

                            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;
                            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;

                            return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log('Refresh token is expired', tokenParts.exp, now);
                    window.location.href = '/login/';
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Refresh token not available.');
                window.location.href = '/login/';
            }
        }

        // specific error handling done elsewhere
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

One issue that is probably notable and that I changed from the tutorial's code is that on line 9 of that file, I changed it to "Bearer " from "JWT " as with JWT I was getting not authorized errors when making requests.

As I said I'm very new to JWT and working with authentication in general, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post your code directly in the question [mre], not as a link to an external site.

Comment: Done! Sorry about that, I figured repo links were fine

Comment: Thanks. No, repo-links are not fine, because the code in repos will change (because you'll fix the error) and then the question becomes invalid and future visitors can't understand the problem anymore.